# Need most optimally structured join query for complicated report

Tags: php, mysql, join, pivot-table, multiple-tables

I'm building a custom report module for my SaaS and need a little advice on a query I'm building (MySQL and PHP). I'm dynamically building a table, and each record that is returned will be one row on that table. It dynamically joins many different tables, and it all works great with the exception of 3 tables I need to join.

All the other tables are a 1-1 LEFT JOIN. For example if I'm querying the employee table and trying to find department_id, it joins just hunky dory. It'll join like this:

```
First | Last  | Dept
John  | Smith | Toy Department
```

The thing that makes this complicated is that those extra 3 tables have a 1-many join. It may also be important to point out that when I make this join it could pull anywhere from 2-50 rows of data. For example if I'm querying the employee table and need to join the clock in/out table it'd end up looking like this:

```
First | Last  | Time
John  | Smith | 8:00 am
John  | Smith | 12:00 pm
John  | Smith | 1:00 pm
John  | Smith | 5:00 pm
```

If I did a right join, the first/last name would be null but I'd still have multiple rows.

The reason why I want to keep them in one row is because with the table that I'm setting up when the report is pulled, when the it hits the  that needs to use one of the 3 1-many tables, it needs to stay in the same data cell (this is out of my control, it just has to happen):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>8:00 am<br />12:00 pm<br />..... </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I really really really want to avoid having to hit that  cell and then running another query to pull out all the data. The reason being is that I could have a report run with thousands of rows with 25+ columns and it would run that same query 25x1000's of rows.

What I was hoping for was something like this when the data gets returned:

```
First | Last  | Time_1  | Time_2   | Time_3  | Time_4
John  | Smith | 8:00 am | 12:00 pm | 1:00 pm | 5:00 pm
```

Some thoughts I've had is to run a while loop in PHP and dynamically build the Joins for MySQL, but I run into the problem of the fact that I'd need to supply how many times to join the table to get that column right. I could technically do:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 50; ++$i) {
    $sql_fields .= "time_clock_{$i}.time AS Time_{$i},";
    $joins .= "LEFT JOIN time_clock AS time_clock_{$i} ON time_clock_{$i}.employee_id = emp.id";
}
$sql_fields = rtrim($sql_fields,',');

mysql_query("SELECT emp.field_blah, emp.field_blah2, {$sql_fields} FROM employees AS emp {$joins} WHERE condition = blah");
```

I'm just afraid that this would really cause some performance issues with MySQL and all the crazy joins I'd have in there. Anyone have a better idea? I'll entertain anything at this point.

Comment: What you want is a pivot table, not the easiest thing to do in MySQL. Perhaps best done in code, but here's a [tutorial](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78).

Comment: @Ami A definite E for effort, but it's too late for me to digest something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Build two queries. One to pull all the people with all the 1:1 elements; then another to pull all your times. Then loop over times in PHP, stuffing them into the people's time array.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.....then just do a lookup for the employee id in the array? Would that array get grossly huge though and cause PHP memory problems?

Comment: If you have a lot of data, then yes, this is not a very good approach. One alternative is to do the full join, then collapse the people with the same id. This will increase the data collected from the DB, but save memory. What you really don't want to do is make N+1 queries.

Comment: Are you talking about doing the full LEFT JOIN like in the example that I did before? What do you mean by collapse by the same id? I don't know how I'd do that appropriately without stripping all the data in that row. You made me think of an idea. See my edit in the original post....

Comment: I mean exactly what you did in your second example (with four John Smiths); then you loop over rows, remembering last ID and last person; if the current ID == last ID, add the time to the last person; otherwise, create a new person and make it the last person.

Comment: Now thinking about it, I could store the table row as a variable and all the field values in an array then let it cycle through the rows (adding to the array) until it recognizes a new id. The print out all the stored values in the array and close the table row and reset the variables....... I may just have to give you some credit for the brilliant stroke of genius and pat myself on the back.

Comment: Now looking more into it, would a TEMPORARY TABLE help solve this? Run my real big query, and then 3 temp tables and then just query the temp tables when I hit the cell? It's taking a bit of a performance hit cause I just tested it out and for 2300 unique records, it was pulled 116000 rows of data due to the joins and that takes some time to chug through so I'm not really gaining that much performance.

Comment: Not really, no. SQL doesn't really do what you want. Then again - why do you want to pull the whole database? If you're working in PHP, you're most likely doing a web application; and showing more than 50-100 of anything to a user is a waste of time. No-one wants to see 2300 records. So unless you have a very good reason for this, my first approach (load everything into memory) should be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT .... FROM employees LEFT JOIN.... LEFT JOIN..."); //even include the one-many tables
    $i = 0;
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //note I'm using array not assoc
        // echo the 1:1 table data
        // when I hit the 1:many field do something like this, yes $j will get reset when the pointer hits the next row....I need more time to think....
        $j = 1;
        while($j) {
            if($rs[$i + $j]['id'] == $rs[$i]['id']) {
                echo $rs[$i + $j]['Time'];
                ++$skip_fields;
            } else {
                $j = 0;
            }
            ++$j;
        }
        // then use $skip_fields to skip $j number of rows that the duplicate employee ids are on and decrement the value as the pointer moves on.
        ++$i;
    }
?>
```

Nevermind.....using the numeric value only hits the column not the row..... oh well. :)